# PAC manager unable to read .ssh files

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sandbox, ubuntu-18.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and had to reinstall PAC manager. It has been installed as a snap, and now it is running sandboxed and with no access to my $HOME/.ssh folder to access my public keys.

Is there any way to solve this issue without having to install it in devmode/classic mode?

Answer (score 2):

I've had (yesterday) the same problem.
The only alternative found, at the moment , is installing this

https://www.asbru-cm.net/

Is a fork of the same project and able to import a pac-yml file with exported connection.
It seems to work well at the moment (only a core-dump after the first import)

Hope this helps
bye

Comment: Well, this does not solve the question, but offers a good workaround. Asbru is based on PAC, it uses the same configuration files... it is almost a drop-in replacement with the same interface. Using Asbru or PAC is irrelevant to me, so it works for me.

Comment: But the original question remains unanswered :-( Asbru is installed as standard software while PAC was installed as a snap. Running as a snap means it is sandboxed and only have permission for the necessary things: this is why it is being so problemmatic. On the other side, it is safer, because it cannot access to places it should not access. If I didn't had the possibility to install alternative software, I would still not know how to solve it :'(